# ¿Cómo instanciar una clase a partir del nombre almacenado en una constante?

Tags: php

¿Hay una forma directa de **instanciar una clase usando una constante que contiene su nombre**? Me explico, tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
const STR = "Lorem ipsum";
const XCLASS = "Foo";

class Foo {
    public function __construct() {

        var_dump( STR );
    }

} //class

class Baz {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Loading ' . XCLASS . ' in Baz...<br>';
        $class = XCLASS;
        new $class();
    }

} //class

class Caz {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Loading ' . XCLASS . ' in Caz...<br>';
        new XCLASS();
    }

} //class


/**
* Runs Tests
*
*/
var_dump( STR );
echo "<hr>";
new Foo();
echo "<hr>";
new Baz();
echo "<hr>";
new Caz(); //Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'XCLASS' not found
```

Puedo instanciar **Foo** usando el código de la clase **Baz**, pero tendré un "error fatal" si instancio **Caz**. ¿Hay otra forma de hacerlo sin volcar el valor de la constante previamente en una variable?

Comment: Puedo preguntar por qué es un problema volcar previamente el valor en una variable?

Answer (score 2):

No puedes hacerlo directamente desde la constante (al menos, hasta donde tengo conocimiento).

Si no quieres hacerlo pasando el valor primero a una variable, puedes usar `eval` para ello, pero personalmente, lo veo menos legible.

```
class Caz {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Loading ' . XCLASS . ' in Caz...<br>';
        eval('new ' . XCLASS . '();');
    }

} //class
```

Comment: Si que parece un poco feo, parece mejor asignar el valor a una variable.

Answer (score 1):

Viendo las respuestas dadas.. diría simplemente: **¡NO es posible!** ni usaría ninguno de estas posibilidades ya que va en contra la idea lo que es un constante.

Si quieres iniciar una clase con un valor almacenado en una constante deberías pasarlo a una variable, como en tu ejemplo `class Baz`.

Si lo quieres un poco más *bonito*, aquí va la propuesta:

```
const XCLASS = "Foo";
const STR    = "Lorem ipsum";

class Foo
{
    public function __construct() {         
        echo STR;
    }
}   

class Caz
{
    private $_xclass = XCLASS;

    public function __construct() {

        echo "Loading {$this->_xclass} in Caz...<br>";          
        new $this->_xclass();
    }
}

new Caz(); 
// Loading Foo in Caz...
// Lorem ipsum
```

Answer (score 0):

En PHP puedes usar el denostado [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php) que evaluará cualquier cadena y la ejecutará en PHP.

```
<?php

const STR = "Lorem ipsum";
const XCLASS = "Foo";

class Caz {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Loading ' . XCLASS . ' in Caz...<br>';
        eval("new " . XCLASS . "();");
    }
}

class Foo {
    public function __construct() {
        var_dump( STR );
    }
}

echo "<hr>";
$foo = new Foo();
echo "<hr>";
$caz = new Caz();
```

cuyo resultado sería:

> string 'Lorem ipsum' (length=11)
>   Loading Foo in Caz...
>   string 'Lorem ipsum' (length=11)

---

Inicialmente entendí mal tu pregunta. Si en lugar de inicializar una clase, lo que quieres es llamar a un método, puedes usar [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.call-user-func.php) (mira el historial de ediciones de esta respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Creo que **la única manera** de crear una nueva instancia de clase usando una constante como nombre de la clase es mediante [`Reflection`](http://php.net/manual/es/reflectionclass.newinstance.php), lo cual no indica que *debas* hacerlo así, sobre todo cuando se puede hacer más fácil usando nombres de variables.

El objetivo de esta respuesta es mostrar que sí se puede. No indica que sea una práctica recomendada.

Aquí traduzco algo sobre `Reflection`, para que sepas cuál es su razón de ser:

> Este grupo de clases fue creado con el propósito expreso de
>   introspeccionar otras clases. Estas clases permiten examinar las
>   propiedades de otras clases recuperando metadatos sobre clases;
>   incluso se puede utilizar para examinar las clases de reflexión en sí.
>
> Reflection proporciona información sobre los modificadores de una
>   clase o interfaz, ya sea que la clase sea final o estática, por
>   ejemplo.
>
> También puede revelar todos los métodos y miembros de datos de una
>   clase y todos los modificadores aplicados a ellos.
>
> Los parámetros pasados a los métodos también pueden ser
>   introspeccionados y los nombres de las variables expuestas. Mediante
>   la reflexión es posible automatizar la documentación de las clases
>   incorporadas o de las clases definidas por el usuario.
>
> Resulta que el repositorio central de información sobre las clases
>   estaba justo delante de nosotros todo el tiempo. PHP nos puede decir
>   todo sobre sí mismo a través del espejo de las clases de reflexión.
>
> Fuente: [Object-Oriented PHP: Concepts, Techniques, and Code
>   By Peter Lavin](https://books.google.es/books?id=7IVIiQLvBW8C&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=%22This%20group%20of%20classes%20was%20created%20for%20the%20express%20purpose%20of%20introspecting%20other%20classes.%20These%20classes%20make%20it%20possible%20to%20examine%20the%20properties%20of%20other%20classes%20by%20retrieving%20metadata%20about%20classes%3B%20you%20can%20even%20use%20them%20to%20examine%20the%20reflection%20classes%20themselves.%22&source=bl&ots=QibbvS4esr&sig=ECjQY-KDnn2Yp-xGykwIVVOqDr4&hl=en&ei=ev4iTsTwLMqSswagwdS5Ag&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22This%20group%20of%20classes%20was%20created%20for%20the%20express%20purpose%20of%20introspecting%20other%20classes.%20These%20classes%20make%20it%20possible%20to%20examine%20the%20properties%20of%20other%20classes%20by%20retrieving%20metadata%20about%20classes%3B%20you%20can%20even%20use%20them%20to%20examine%20the%20reflection%20classes%20themselves.%22&f=false)

Por ejemplo:

```
   $class = (new ReflectionClass(XCLASS))->newInstance();
```

Así funciona:

```
<?php


const STR = "Lorem ipsum";
const XCLASS = "Foo";

class Foo {
    public function __construct() {

        var_dump( STR );
    }

} //class

class Baz {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Loading ' . XCLASS . ' in Baz...<br>';
 //       $class = XCLASS;
   $class = (new ReflectionClass(XCLASS))->newInstance();     
//        new $class();
    }

} //class

class Caz {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Loading ' . XCLASS . ' in Caz...<br>';
//        new XCLASS();
   $class = (new ReflectionClass(XCLASS))->newInstance();     


    }

} //class


/**
* Runs Tests
*
*/
var_dump( STR );
echo "<hr>";
new Foo();
echo "<hr>";
new Baz();
echo "<hr>";
new Caz();

?>
```

---

#### Resultado:

```
string(11) "Lorem ipsum"
<hr>string(11) "Lorem ipsum"
<hr>Loading Foo in Baz...<br>string(11) "Lorem ipsum"
<hr>Loading Foo in Caz...<br>string(11) "Lorem ipsum"
```

Comment: Esto es demasiado.. usar una API para hacer simplemente `$a = CONST;` :S

Comment: He editado poniendo más información @aldanux. El objetivo de la respuesta era mostrar la _posibilidad_ de hacerlo. No todo lo _posible_ es _debido_.

Comment: Interesante. Estuve haciendo cosas recientemente con 'ReflectionClass' y no se me habría ocurrido, supongo que estaba buscando añadir unas comillas, la constante entre paréntesis o algo de ese tipo, que no sabía para que el interprete la identificará como constante... Algunas pruebas hice al azar... Al final ver las diferentes formas de hacer algo es interesante y parece que la forma más sencilla que conocía es más legible y aparentemente eficiente.